# Mysql JOIN error with QueryBuilder

Tags: mysql, laravel-query-builder

I have a question! This is my code:

```
public static function getMessages($threader_id){
        $messages = DB::table('messages_messages')
             ->join('messages_participants', function ($join) {
                $join->on('messages_participants.id_message', '=', 'messages_messages.id')
                    ->where('messages_participants.id_threader', '=', $threader_id);
                 })
         ->get();
        return $messages;
}
```

I got error:Undefined variable: threader_id
No idea why,beacuse when I try to `return $threader_id;` its return me the value.
Any idea? Thx

Comment: Remove ' = ' from where clause.  ->where('messages_participants.id_threader',  $threader_id);

Comment: No. Still the same error:But if I try ->where('messages_participants.id_threader', '=', 3); its working!

Comment: Can you print the query, and check what is actual query .

dd(DB::getQueryLog());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way:

```
$messages = DB::table('messages_messages')
             ->join('messages_participants', function ($join)  use ($threader_id) {
                $join->on('messages_participants.id_message', '=', 'messages_messages.id')
                    ->where('messages_participants.id_threader',$threader_id);
                 })
             ->select('messages_messages.*')
         ->get();
```